# Bash union of two directories in one statement

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a command that takes one location input (intended for a single directory of files), but I need to run it on files in several locations. While I'd normally run it on `*/*.type`, I'm looking for some way to run the command over (`*/dirA/*.type` AND `dirB/*.type`).

I basically need all files of `*.type` within a directory structure, but they're not all at the same directory level (or I'd just do `*/*/*.type` or something to grab them all). Unfortunately they're in a particular layout for a reason, which I can't just reorganize to make this command run.

Is there any bash shortcut/command/whatever-it's-called that I could use to get both sets of files at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can say

```
dir{A,B}/*.type
```

For example running this with ls command

```
root@do:/tmp# ls dir{A,B}/*.type
dirA/test.type  dirB/test.type
```

Comment: Note that the brackets can enclose part of the directories' name, so if the directories were really named `dirA` and `dirB` one could use `dir{A,B}`

Comment: This is super cool, and I did not know this. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

If the command works when you pass one wildcard in, that means it is expecting a list of file names. In that case you can pass it two wildcards just as easily.

```
command */dirA/*.type dirb/*.type
```

Comment: This is exactly what I should have thought of (and the reason it seemed like such a "dumb question" to me initially!) Thanks!